# for loop auto increment variable javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am trying to do an exercise in freecodecamp, where we have to search through an array and return the largest number inside the subarray, when i was trying to do it using the following code:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  let newArr = []
  for(let i = 0 ; i< arr.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j< arr[i].length; j++) {
      if(arr[i][j] > arr[i][j+1]) {
        newArr[i] = arr[i][j]
        console.log(i)
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

here the when I `console.log(i)` it returns `0 1 3 3`
never entering the 3rd loop where `i=2`. can someone please explain why is this happening?

Comment: Add `console.log(i, arr[i][j], arr[i][j+1], arr[i][j] > arr[i][j+1])` just before `if`, and all will become clear to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find the largest number, you should use `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` as the initial values of `newArr`, and use `newArr[i]` as the compare value. so the code is like this:

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  let negaInf = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY; 
  let newArr = [negaInf, negaInf,negaInf, negaInf];
  for(let i = 0 ; i< arr.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j< arr[i].length; j++) {
      if(arr[i][j] > newArr[i]) {
        newArr[i] = arr[i][j]
        console.log(i)
      }
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

the reason of that is in the third array, the value of numbers are increasing, when `i = 2, j = 0`, it compare 32(`arr[2][0]`) and 35(`arr[2][1]`), condition false, 35(`arr[2][1]`) and 37(`arr[2][2]`), condition false, 37(`arr[2][2]`) and 39(`arr[2][3]`), condition false, 39(`arr[2][3]`) and `undefined`(`arr[2][4]`) (Yes your code has a out of index access), condition false. so it had not change the value of `newArr[2]`

Comment: by the way, Javascript have `Math.max()` method to get max value, like this: `let arr =[1,2,3]; console.log(Math.max(...arr);// output 3`